# How to append the string variables using stringWithFormat having format?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I am trying to append with following code.

**working fine**

```
stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"image.png"]];
```

this is not working

```
stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"ankita/k/image.png"]];
```

Can't we add folder structure.

I need to add folder structure as well.

Any idea ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
NSError *error;
NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *foldername = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/FolderName"];

if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:foldername]) {
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:foldername withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:&error];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use the stringWithFormat:?

as I see you need only

```
[baseString stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"ankita/k/image.png"];
```

and I've checked, this code works well...

Comment: what do you mean, can you provide your source string, and the result?